# Displaying Validation Error Messages Beside The Input Box in Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
<form action="/regvalid", method="POST">
 {{ csrf_field()}}

<h2>Personal Information</h2>
<hr>
<table>
<tr>
<td>First Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname" value="{{ old('fname') }}"></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td>Last Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gender:</td>
<td>
<div class="radio">
<label><input type="radio" value="male"  name="gender">Male</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="female"  name="gender">Female<label>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mobile Phone:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="mp"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tel No.:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="telno"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Birth Date:</td>
<td><input type="date" name="bd" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="add"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><input type="email" name="email"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Website:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="website"></td>
</tr>
```

I have already their error rules in the controller;

> $rules = [
> 'fname' => 'required|max:50',
> 'lname' => 'required|max:50',
> 'gender' => 'required',
> 'mp' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s-+()]*)$/|min:11',
> 'telno' => 'required|min:11|numeric',
> 'bd' => 'required|date',
> 'add' => 'required|max:100',
> 'email' => 'required|email',
> 'website' => 'required|url',
> 'username' => 'required|min:6|max:20',
> 'pass' => 'required|min:6|max:12',
> 'repass' => 'required|min:6|max:12',
>
> ```
>     ];
> ```

and also the code that will show all;

> @if(count($errors)>0)
>
>   @foreach ($errors->all() as $errors)
> - {{ $errors}}
>   @endforeach
>
> @endif

I want to display the error messages on each one of the input boxes besides them. I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Displaying error message

**Method 1:**

```
 <input type="text" name="firstname">
    @if($errors->has('firstname'))
        <div class="error">{{ $errors->first('firstname') }}</div>
    @endif
```

**Method 2:**

```
@error('firstname')
    <div class="error">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

These two ways of doing it